# Bitmap se duplica en diferente ImageView Android

Tags: android, android-imageview, bitmap, onactivityresult

les vengo con una duda, que estoy seguro que es super sencilla, pero a mi me tiene ya varios dias sacando canas.

Les explico, en una actividad tengo 2 imagenes, la imagen A y la imagen B, al darle click a la imagen A, se abre la galeria del telefono podemos escoger una foto (Estoy usando una libreria para recortar la imagen adicional) luego que podemos recortarla, sucede el problema, y es que la imagen se me coloca tanto en el ImageView de la imagen A, como de la B y solo deberia de quedarme colocada en el ImageView A, si hago con la B lo mismo, al escoger la imagen de la galeria y recortarla, se me coloca En ambos ImageView, y la idea es que la imagen escogida en la imagen A quede en el ImageView A y la B igual, y tener 2 imagenes distintas.

Estoy seguro que el problema en la parte del Bitmap, que no se que carajo hace a pesar que creo que todo esta bien, pero mejor le dejo esto a los experto, a ver si me ayudan con este pequeño problema y poder seguir avanzando en mis conocimientos, de antemano, espero hayan entendido todo, se les quiere.

Les dejo por aca todo el codigo que utilizo:

-----------Layout----------

```
    <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                                        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                                            android:id="@+id/imagenA"
                                            android:layout_width="60dp"
                                            android:layout_height="60dp"
                                            android:src="@drawable/subirfoto"
                                            app:civ_border_width="3dp"
                                            app:civ_border_color="@color/banner" />


                                        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                                            android:id="@+id/imagenB"
                                            android:layout_width="60dp"
                                            android:layout_height="60dp"
                                            android:src="@drawable/subirfoto"
                                            app:civ_border_width="3dp"
                                            app:civ_border_color="@color/banner" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/subirfotos"
android:layout_width="100dp"
android:layout_height="60dp" />

                                </LinearLayout>
```

-----------Java----------

```
public class crearcampeonato extends AppCompatActivity {

    private CircleImageView imagenA, imagenB;
    private static final int ImageBack = 1;
    Uri ImageResultadoUri, ImageUri;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_crearcampeonato);

        imagenA = findViewById(R.id.imagenA);
        imagenB = findViewById(R.id.imagenB);

        imagenA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onClick(View v) {
                     Intent intent = new Intent();
                     intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                     intent.setType("image/*");
                     startActivityForResult(intent, ImageBack);
            }
             });

        imagenB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(intent, ImageBack);
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == ImageBack && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data!=null)
        {
            ImageUri = data.getData();
            CropImage.activity(ImageUri)
                    .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                    .setAspectRatio(1,1)
                    .start(this);
        }
        if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
                assert result != null;
                ImageResultadoUri = result.getUri();
        }

        try {
            Bitmap bitmap1 = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), ImageResultadoUri);
            Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap1, 200,200,true);
            imagenA.setImageBitmap(bitmap1);

            Bitmap bitmap2 = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), ImageResultadoUri);
            Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap2, 200,200,true);
            imagenB.setImageBitmap(bitmap2);

        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

-----------Boton Subir imagenes Base Datos----------

```
subirfotos.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (ImageUri!=null)
        {
            StorageReference FilePath = carpeta.child(Objects.requireNonNull
                    (ImageResultadoUri.getLastPathSegment()));
            FilePath.putFile(ImageResultadoUri).addOnCompleteListener(new
        OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {

        if (task.isSuccessful())
         {
        Toast.makeText(crearcampeonato.this, "Foto Cargada Correctamente",
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

          }
          else
          {
          String mensaje = Objects.requireNonNull(task.getException()).toString();
          Toast.makeText(crearcampeonato.this, "Error:" + mensaje, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }

          }
         });
        }

            }
        });
```

Comment: Por favor si pudieras incluir tu layout para saber qué elementos tienes en tu vista.

Comment: Hola Fernando mi layout solo tiene 2 imageview en un linearlayout, simple.

Comment: Hola fernando he colocado arriba el layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es normal que te muestra la imagen en ambos imageView, el motivo es que en el onActivityResult, en el try catch estás realizando la siguiente acción:

```
  Bitmap bitmap1 = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), ImageResultadoUri);
  Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap1, 200,200,true);
  imagenA.setImageBitmap(bitmap1)

  Bitmap bitmap2 = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(),ImageResultadoUri);
  Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap2, 200,200,true);                
  imagenB.setImageBitmap(bitmap2);
```

Es decir, crear dos bitmaps exactamente iguales y además setear el imageDrawable de ambos imageCircle.

Comment: Hola Manuel gracias por responder, y que me recomiendas exactamente crear un solo bitmap. Soy un poco nuevo en esto

Comment: una solución rápida es crear una variable en el scope de la clase que referencia a la vista seleccionada (mageView currentImageView;)... ahora al seleccionar un imageView, por ejemplo el A, seteas la variable (currentImageView = imagenA).  En el startActivityForResult creas el bitmap y después seteas la vista guardada: currentImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap).  *** Y sólo crea el bitmap una vez, no dupliques código y, si necesitas este fragmento de código, extráelo en un método.

Comment: Vale, estoy realizando, escribire en un rato Manuel, Gracias por tu sugerencia.

Comment: Hola manuel, implemente tu sugeencia y perfecto, ya me toma cada Imageview la imagen eescogida a la galeria, BRAVOOOO. 

Ahora bien tengo otra duda relacionada con lo mismo, no se si debo de abrir un post nuevo o la realizo aca...

La duda es que agregue un boton, y ese boton tiene la funcion de subir dichas imagenes a la base de datos de firebase, el botonme hace el funcionamiento que deseo, pero solo me sube una de las imagenes, no me sube ambas fotos. Deje el codigo de la funcion del boton arriba, por si me puedes orientar con ello, De antemano un millon.

Comment: Debes abrir otro post y recuerda valorar las respuestas que te fueron útiles

Comment: Hola Manuel, buen dia, ya cree la pregunta nueva, a ver si chequeas el codigo y me orientas amigo, de antemano Gracias por cualquier ayuda. Exitos.